# Loop and array problem with stopping at one element

Tags: arrays, c, loops

Scroll for more details

My code :

```
     #include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int T[50], X[50], TEST[50] ,N, i, j, n_indices=0;
    do { printf("Enter size of aray : ");
         scanf("%d", &N);
    } while ( N <= 0 || N > 50);
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    //Filling the array
    printf("\nRemplissage :");
    for ( i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ )
    {
        printf("\n T[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &T[i]);
    }
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    //Array
    printf("\nArray : ");
    for ( i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ )
    {
        printf("\n T[%d] = %d ", i, T[i]);      
    }
    
    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    printf("\n /// Solution /// : ");
    //Problem part
    
    for( i=0 ; i< N ; i++ )
    {
        TEST[i] = T[i];
    }
    
        
    for ( i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ )
    {   
        for ( j=0 ; j < N ; j++ )
        {
            if ( TEST[i] == TEST[j])
            {
            X[n_indices] = j;
            n_indices++;
            }
        }
                
        //Show results
        for ( j = 0 ; j < n_indices ; j++ )
        {
        printf("\n T[%d] = %d ", X[j], TEST[X[j]]);     
        }
        printf("\n //////////// ");
        n_indices=0;
        
        //Removing T[i]
                
        for ( i=0 , j=0 ; i<N ; i++)
        {
        if (TEST[i] != T[i] )
        {
            TEST[j]=TEST[i];
            j++;
        }
        } 
        
        
            
    }
```

In the last loop the code stops after one loop.
The purpose of this program is to show how many times each element is repeated in the array with its correspondant position.
If possible i would love to know what problem caused this.

Input :

```
    T[0] = 1
    T[1] = 2
    T[2] = 2
    T[3] = 1
    T[4] = 5
    T[5] = 1
```

what i want as Output:

```
    T[0] = 1
    T[3] = 1
    T[5] = 1
    /////////
    T[1] = 2
    T[2] = 2
    /////////
    T[4] = 5
    /////////
```

what i got :

```
    T[0] = 1
    T[3] = 1
    T[5] = 1
    /////////
```

Comment: Please avoid code which needs to be scrolled horizontally AND vertically to be completly read.

Comment: You are overriding the external `i` in one of your internal loops (`for ( i=0 , j=0 ; i<N ; i++)`)

Comment: so will using another variable solve it? @obe

Comment: I didn't actually analyze the entire code, I just looked specifically for overrides like this. If all the rest is correct then yes...

Comment: Even after changing it, the T[i] isnt completly deleted

Comment: Are you sure j loop shouldn't start at `j = i + 1;` or something similar as right now you are testing `i` against itself often, which will always be true.  If you are looking for matches, you don't want to compare indexes against themselves.

Comment: The clean up code also probably belongs outside the `for(i...)` loop.  I don't think you want to compare a cleanup for every internal loop, but I could be wrong.

Comment: yes, the original problem i had was when determining that T[i] is repeated twice i had to removed the second repetition else it will go over the loop again

Comment: @JerryJeremiah after execution its clear tha T[i] isnt deleted as its shown twice

Comment: The current algorithm, as is, does not support the stated goal: _"The purpose of this program is to show how many times each element is repeated in the array with its correspondent position."_ Using a simple sort before the ***solution*** section would be useful as it would group the values in ascending order making it less complicated to count the occurrences of each, then outputting them in the sorted order.  Have you considered that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the final code ^^

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int T[50], X[50], TEST[50] ,N, i, j, n_indices=0;
    do { printf("Entrer la taille du tableau : ");
         scanf("%d", &N);
    } while ( N <= 0 || N > 50);

////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Remplissage
printf("\nRemplissage :");
for ( i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ )
{
    printf("\n T[%d] = ", i);
    scanf("%d", &T[i]);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////

//Affichage
printf("\n Affichage avant traitement : ");
for ( i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ )
{
    printf("\n T[%d] = %d ", i, T[i]);      
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////
printf("\n /// Solution /// : ");
//traitement

for( i=0 ; i< N ; i++ )
{
    TEST[i] = T[i];
}

    
for ( i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ )
{   
    for ( j=0 ; j < N ; j++ )
    {
        if ( TEST[i] == TEST[j])
        {
        if(j >= i)
        {X[n_indices] = j;
        n_indices++;
        }
        else
        break;
        }
    }
            
    //Affichage des resultats
    if(n_indices >0)
    {
    for ( j = 0 ; j < n_indices ; j++ )
    {
    printf("\n T[%d] = %d ", X[j], TEST[X[j]]);     
    }
    printf("\n //////////// ");
    }


    n_indices=0;
        
        
        
        
            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
for ( i=0 , j=0 ; i<N ; i++)
```

Is a sub loop of this:

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ )
```

You cannot change the value of `i` in the sub loop, and reasonably expect that doing so will not adversely affect the value assignments of any variable that references it as an index.  Including the likely occurrence of Undefined Behavior when the index write to memory that you do not own.

The take away here is to pay attention to the indices in use and do not double increment them.  If needed, choose a different index variable to use inside sub loops to avoid over-writing those in the outer loop.

***Edit*** Your stated goal is:

> *"The purpose of this program is to show how many times each element is repeated in the array with its correspondent position."*

The following adaptation of your code is to illustrate how you might meet this goal via simplification of code made possible by sorting arrays prior to evaluating them.

See comments in-line to explain changes to this (*extensive*) adaptation of your code.

```
void sort(int array[], int n);
void swap(int *xp, int *yp);

int main(void)// main() is not a correct signature, use minimum int main(void)
{
    int T[50]={0}, TEST[50]={0} ,N=0, i=0, j=0;//Its a bad habit to leave variables uninitialized
    do { printf("Enter size of array : ");                             //initialize all of them
         scanf("%d", &N);
    } while ( N <= 0 || N > 50);
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    //Filling the array
    printf("\nFilling array :");
    for ( i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ )
    {
        printf("\n T[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &T[i]);
    }
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    //Array before sort
    printf("\nArray : ");
    for ( i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ )
    {
        printf("\n T[%d] = %d ", i, T[i]);      
    }
    
    //simplify following algorithm by sorting array first
    sort(T, N);
    
    //Array after sort
    printf("\nArray : ");
    for ( i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ )
    {
        printf("\n T[%d] = %d ", i, T[i]);      
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    printf("\n /// Solution /// : ");
    //Problem part
    
    for( i=0 ; i< N ; i++ )
    {
        TEST[i] = T[i];
    }
    //Now that both TEST and T are arranged in ascending order, 
    //only one loop is needed, and the comparison should work:    
    //for ( i=0 ; i < N-1 ; i++ )//adjust limits from beginning to N-1
    //{   
        for ( j=1 ; j < N ; j++ )
        {
            if ( TEST[j-1] == T[j])//note adjustments in indexes
            {
                printf("\n T[%d] = %d ", j, T[j-1]);
                //X[n_indices] = j;//no longer needed
                //n_indices++;//no longer needed
            }
            else
            {
                //print last element of value
                printf("\n T[%d] = %d ", j-1, T[j-1]);//last element in value group
                printf("\n //////////// ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n T[%d] = %d ", j-1, T[j-1]);//last element in array
    //}
                
 /*   //this section is no longer needed    
        //Show results
        for ( j = 0 ; j < n_indices ; j++ )
        {
            printf("\n T[%d] = %d ", X[j], TEST[X[j]]);     
        }
        printf("\n //////////// ");
        n_indices=0;
        
        //Removing T[i]
                
        for ( i=0 , j=0 ; i<N ; i++)
        {
            if (TEST[i] != T[i] )
            {
                TEST[j]=TEST[i];
                j++;
            }
        } 
        
        
            
    } */
    return 0;//int main(void) requres a return statement
}

void sort(int array[], int n)
{
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)      
  
       // Last i elements are already in place   
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) 
           if (array[j] > array[j+1])
              swap(&array[j], &array[j+1]);
}

void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like this ? https://onlinegdb.com/BkOzMaJrO Because it still is only show the first element. Sorry for bothering you

Comment: The code in the link makes the same error of double incrementing `i`.  Also, per my comment under your post, this edit to the answer above illustrated that pre-sorting arrays would greatly simplify the evaluation of the arrays in terms of separating section by element values.